# convert.toint32について

Tags: c#

お世話になっています。

```
const int LENGTH_SIZE = 5;  
byte[] Length = new byte[LENGTH_SIZE];
Buffer.BlockCopy(byteData, nowPos, Length, 0, LENGTH_SIZE);
int Size = Convert.ToInt32(BytesConvert.ToHexString(Length), 16);
```

バイトを変換しようとした時に
「UInt32 型の値が大きすぎるか、または小さすぎます。」
Lengthの配列の中身は
[250][51][137][241][32]となってます。
サイズが大きいから落ちるのは納得できるのですが、回避方法が浮かびません。
ご教授いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すべてのバイトが0でないことから、`int`型に格納することは無理だと思います。`long`型への変更を検討してください。

この場合`Convert.Int64`を使用しますが、メッセージからすると`BytesConvert.ToHexString`の内部で例外が発生しているのではないかと思われます。このメソッドは.NET Framework標準ではないのでそちらの実装を変更するか、`BytesConvert.ToHexString`を使用せずに自分で変換を行う必要があります。

一番素直に直接計算すると、以下のようになります。

```
long Size = Length[0] * 0x100000000L
          + Length[1] * 0x1000000L
          + Length[2] * 0x10000L
          + Length[3] * 0x100L
          + Length[4];
```

しかし添字の並びがこの順でよいかはデータの仕様によります。